# Behringer UMC404HD Mic (line in) not working

Tags: ubuntu, audio, microphone

Full disclosure,  I asked this on reddit,  but no luck, so I am trying here.  I desperately need even just a direction as to where to look.

I recently upgraded from ubuntu 20.10 to 21.10 and now my mic wont work. In fact, none of the 4 lines in are even recognized. Output is the same and works great! (I love this sound card!) Anyway, when I try pavucontrol, It is listed, and shows that sound IS coming in. (The db spikes when I tap the mic) But there is no port dropdown. In my sound settings in ubuntu, it is not displayed as an option for input. It is for output, like I said, every thing is fine there. My studio presets, (I use Jackd and Cadence) no longer show inputs on that device.

So I think it has to do with some driver/codec something that was in 20.10 that is no longer there. Any suggestions to hunt this down?

Answer (score 0):

I have one of those and agree, sounds amazing
The same is happening to me too, but on linux mint (which is about the same. it is ubuntu based distro)
Back to the problem, on Linux Mint, I just found out that the new version 21.1 uses pipewire and not pulse audio alone.
run `sudo inxi -A`  and you will see if it's using in my case it indeed was.
I do professional recording and see that when I am running jack (it does not appear either) but it works on Ardour and Harrison MixBus
PAVU control displays it is working
So I  will keep reading, and if I find anything I will post it here
What I did already was remove pipewire. I need qjackctl for many applications

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/437479)